# Performance: CTE in an "IN"-Operator

Tags: sql-server, performance, cte

I've got a query with a CTE (getting all children of a parent) followed by a main statement using the "IN"-Operator to filter for the CTE's output.

Roughly looks like this:

```
WITH cte_table AS (...)

SELECT (stuff)

FROM tables JOIN more tables

WHERE ID IN

(SELECT ID FROM cte_table)
```

The CTE runs fast by itself. The main query runs fast if fed with the CTE's output manually. Fast means that it takes no noticeable time. But when I combine both it takes almost 20 seconds.

Any ideas for solutions? Or, what is probably more important to me, the reason why it could take that long?

Comment: Adding a "slow" execution plan would be helpful

Comment: Does `id` in `cte_table` is unique? If not - distinct it (maybe using second CTE). Than move this condition from WHERE clause to FROM clause in a form of `FROM tables JOIN more tables INNER JOIN cte_table ON sometable.id = cte_table.id`.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Didn't know about the execution plans, analyzing that atm. There's a clustered index scan that apparently takes 73% of the total cost, not sure why it does that only when I combine CTE and main query though.@Akina The IDs are unique and that part doesn't create too much cost I believe, with my current test scenario it only gives out some 5 values.

Comment: Basically, it has to check cursively for each row. Why not try am exists or possibly better, an Outer Join?

Answer (score 1):

You could try refactoring the query to use equivalent, but different, syntax.

IN is more-or-less an inner join. So your query could become

```
...
FROM cte_table JOIN tables JOIN more tables
...
```

For your query a row has to be in the CTE output to be returned. The same applies to this inner join syntax. The two queries are equivalent.

Although you and I know these two are interchangeable the query optimizer doesn't always realize this. So by giving it a different place to start from you can (sometimes) end up with a different plan.

Really need to see the table definitions and the "slow" plan for a proper answer, though.